# Bootstrap 4 on Wide Displays: Centering, and Ensuring an Image is no Taller than Text that Wraps it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, sorry for the noob question. I don't expect the answers here to add much to the 21st century's understanding of computer science, but I am grateful for the help of the community.

I am attempting to, in respect of the CodePen project linked below:

1. Have the main image and caption centered in any view, and
2. Have the following behavior in respect of the crater image and associated paragraph text:

   - when the paragraph text is larger than the image, the text wraps around the image (on smaller displays)
   - when the paragraph text shrinks in height (wider displays), the image should never be taller than it.

This is a link to the CodePen of the project, which (admittedly) has a bit of debug code in it as JS, and with the ids called `#hacky-*`:
http://codepen.io/NotAnAmbiTurner/pen/GrGmaq?editors=0010. Some of my attempts to make this work have actually made the page a little worse (the image underlays some of the proceeding paragraphs now, at certain sizes).

It's apparent when you grow/shrink the width of the display that the div containing the image is changing heights, so the jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", resizeImage)

function resizeImage() {
  var x = $("#hacky-p-id").outerHeight();
  $("#hacky-img-id").css("height", x);
  $("#hacky-h3-id").text("Height: " + x);
  console.log("yes!");
}
```

is having an effect, just definitely not the one I want it to (actually sort of the inverse). It's complicated by the fact it's supposed to be an `img-fluid`, which I would have thought would work well with a defined height, but I don't have the knowledge base to fully comprehend what might be going on behind the scenes here.

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**problem 1**: You are loading `jquery.min.js` after `bootstrap.min.js`

**problem 2**: You are not loading `tether.min.js`, required by Bootstrap 4.

**problem 3**: You've placed `#hacky-p-id` on the wrong paragraph...

**problem 4**: ...you've placed `#hacky-img-id` on the container of the image, and that is not going to shrink the image.

At which point I stopped counting, as I discovered your markup was utterly broken. In `HTML` it is very important to close all paired tags you are opening.

Another thing you should avoid is to have nested `container-fluid`s. The only accepted nesting Bootstrap `container`s is when you place a `container` as the direct child of a `container-fluid`. Most other `container` nesting will cause margin/padding issues that most people find quite hard to debug/fix. In effect, once you have a `container`, you don't need another one inside it (apart from the case above) - all you need is `row` > `col-*-*` combinations.

Here's a [*"fixed"* version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyKeqM) of your pen. However, i did not do what you initially asked for, and that's  shrinking the image according to paragraph's height, because I happen to believe it is an extremely poor design decision, as it has the potential to generate serious rendering problems: when you resize the image so its height matches the paragraph height, it will change width, making the paragraph reflow and (potentially) change height, making the image resize again, making the paragraph reflow again and so on... This has the potential to enter rendering loops which will stall slow devices and cause the browser to crash. In short, it's a clear case of ***never do this***.

Other decisions I don't particularly agree with but haven't "fixed" are:

- placing all page inside a `.jumbotron`
- expressing font sizes in `vmax`. You should use `rem` with fallback on `px`. It's the safe and sound solution.

Comment: Thanks. I found the rem and px this really useful - I saw a few posts with diverse opinions and I wasn't sure which to go with; I like the rem/px best - the whole vmax (or even vw) units are a little more difficult. I am new to front-end (as you may have guessed this isn't a professional project), so I think some of the errors are a result of it being mid-hack, but the infinite loop thing is a really good point I never thought of. How would you do something like that - getting text to wrap, but then scaling down the image in bigger views, or what other design choice would you make instead?

Comment: I realize some of the above questions are answered in your code. I'm going to have to spend some time with your example to really understand what you did. I'm wondering if there's a good way you know of that I can run a diff between what you wrote and what I wrote? That would help.

Comment: The "modern" way of doing that is to have two containers side by side. The one with the picture has a fixed bottom area for caption but, in effect, the image is used as background image and is cropped on different screens. The height of this image area is not really set by the image height, but by the left-hand side paragraphs height. Works really well but it's important to use images that can be cropped (without texts or important people who cannot be cropped, etc)...

Comment: So instead of changing the image's height, you use it as background to the side column and it will adapt to the column height if it has `background-size:cover;`. Depending on image you may also want to use `background-origin` to control what sides of the image get cropped.